# All my images (png, jpg) appear on the view but not on the phone/emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-drawable

I tried with other image jpg/png, different ways to add image asset, other directories (@mipmap/ic_launcher, which is a default image, it should works!) but the problem is still there. My gradle version is 2.2.2. It doesn't seem to work with any kind of images, except drawables added by default activities, buttons, etc.

My ImageView:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_white_humit"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/logo_humit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

[On the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEzZL.png)

[On the emulator (same thing on my phone)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOSyO.png)

Comment: can you post some code here

Comment: Screenshots uploaded

Comment: try with any other image jpg/png. does this appears on your emulator or phone?

Comment: check your java code also are you making it invisible/gone on runtime :)

Comment: I will also suggest the same thing as Piyush's answer

Comment: I tried with other image jpg/png but I have the same problem. @QadirHussain How it could be possible?

Comment: can see it if you remove all positioning on the image view (i.e., wrap_content/wrap_content and remove the marginTop (that could be it)), or if you use normal Src instead of CompatSrc?

Comment: another good thing is making the view have a different background colour for debugging, just to make sure the view is definitely being drawn

Comment: @Alex Thanks a lot! I used "android:src" instead of "app:srcCompat" and it works! It's weird because app:srcCompat is the default when I add an image on my view, I didn't know there where other ways. Do you know the difference?

Comment: That's weird - I take it that's the visual editor? I always try to use AppCompat unless I know I don't have to, but I never seem to have needed to use compatSrc. I can't give you much more explanation than saying: Android has App and AppCompat, AppCompat is support (Compatibility). You could look into these if you like - you get some interesting errors sometimes when you accidently cross these.

Answer (score 0):

Must be sure that you are using `appcompact` library.

`app:srcCompat` as it is an attribute defined within `AppCompat`

with namespace

> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

Also if your gradle version is `2.0` or `>2.0` then add this in `build.gradle` file

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
   vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
 }
}
```

Comment: Namespace is already in my xml file. I added "vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true" in the build.gradle file but the problem persists...

Comment: What is your gradle version ?

Comment: My gradle version is 2.2.2